# Django How to filter with multiple keywords

Tags: django

I'm filtering data from database based on "keyskill". For eample I'm having following skills

1. Java
2. python
3. django
4. Html
5. Css

While filtering with the keyword "python" in my search box the datas related to that keyword is fetched from db. But when I search with keyword "python,Java" in my search box, none of the details is fetched.

How to filter data from database by using two keywords.

*views.py*

```
def search_result(request):

    search = request.GET['skills']
    query = Q(key_skills__icontains=search )
    details = jobs.objects.filter(query)
    return render_to_response('registration/searchresult.html', {'details': details})
```

*models.py*

```
class jobs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    jobsummary = models.TextField()
    jobdetails = models.TextField()
    key_skills = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    min_exp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    max_exp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

> for Example in my jobs table having 5 records having key skills (1.java 2.Python 3.Html ..etc..) While entering in search box as "Java" it displayed their details but while entering in search box as "java Html" it doesn't display anything so, I need here to display both java and html details

Comment: Could you paste the code you're currently using? Also, what is your setup? What Django version, are you using the django-filter app etc? Last but not least, where are you filtering this? In a user-facing form? In the admin?

Answer (score 0):

file.html

```
$(document).keypress(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
        var keyword = $("#id_search_field").val();
        if ( keyword == 'SEARCH') {
            keyword = '';
        }
        if ((keyword != '')){
            window.location.href = "/search_view/?key=" + keyword
        }
        window.location.href = "/search_view/?keyword=" + keyword



        }
    });

    function keyword(){

        var keyword = $("#id_search_field").val();
        if ( keyword == '{% trans "SEARCH" %}') {
            keyword = '';
        }
        if (keyword != ''){
            window.location.href = "/search_view/?key=" + keyword
        }
        window.location.href = "/search_view/?keyword=" + keyword

    }

    <body>

    <input type="text" name="place" placeholder="SEARCH" id="id_search_field"/></div>
    <div class="searc">
      <a href="#"><img src="/static/img/admin/search.png" alt="searchbox" onClick="keyword();"/></a>
    </div>
    {% for i in list %}
      {{i.keyskill}}
    {% endfor %}   

    </body>
```

search_view(Your views.py)

```
def search_view(request): 
    key = request.GET.get('keyword')
    if key is not None: 
        key = key.lstrip()
    if key :
        list = Dbtablename.objects.filter(Q(keyskill__icontains = key)).order_by('-modified_at')
    else:
        list = Dbtablename.objects.filter().order_by('-modified_at')
```